# Comparison of datetime after is not working fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, comparison

Please have a look at below code-

```
#rails default time
2.1.4 :101 > time1 = User.first.created_at
 => Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:23:49 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :102 > time1.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 

#convert time into timestamp
2.1.4 :103 > time1.to_i
 => 1421677429 
2.1.4 :104 > timestamp = User.first.created_at.to_i
 => 1421677429 

#convert same timestamp again into datetime
2.1.4 :106 > DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s,'%s')
 => Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:23:49 +0000 
2.1.4 :107 > DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s,'%s').class
 => DateTime 

#Convert time into timezone and comparing the time
2.1.4 :112 > time2 = DateTime.strptime(timestamp.to_s,'%s').in_time_zone
  => Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:23:49 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :118 > time1
 => Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:23:49 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :119 > time2
 => Mon, 19 Jan 2015 14:23:49 UTC +00:00 
2.1.4 :120 > time1.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 
2.1.4 :121 > time2.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone 
2.1.4 :122 > time1 == time2
 => false
2.1.4 :124 > time1 > time2
 => true
```

I'm just wondering that why this happenns? As both the time(time1 and time2) belongs to same class and looks same but they are not equal. Please share your views and help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

`time1` and `time2` are floats, output of `to_f` should show they aren't equal

Comment: But there is any other way to make them equal? Actually my requirement is for firing a query e.g. User.where(:created_at.gt => time1). In this case I can't use :created_at.gt.to_f. Please give me some other suggestions.

Comment: use `to_i` or `to_s` before you compare them

Comment: But do you think User.where(:created_at.gt.to_i => time1) will work? It is nor working.

Comment: If you don't know the exact time, use a range?
 `User.where( created_at: time1.beginning_of_day..time1.end_of_day )`?